# read a very very big file with python

Tags: python, file, text

What is the best solution to process each line of a text file whose size is about 500 MB?

The proposal to which I had thought :

```
def files(mon_fichier):
    while True:
        data = mon_fichier.read(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data

fichier = open('tonfichier.txt', 'r')
for bloc in files(fichier):
    print bloc
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The same way you'd process each line of a file that was 20 lines long. Is there something specific you need help with?

Comment: @Brian There will he not a memory problem?

Comment: Do you need to have more than one line in memory at a time? Your question doesn't give much detail.

Comment: @Brian I treat every line, but given that they are very numerous, there is inevitably a matter of time and memory. That is why I seek the best solution to address these two problems.

Comment: @user653861: The answer you have selected is a nonsense; see my comment on it.

Comment: @John Machin It is a question primarily theoretical, I read a book by Alex Martelli seems to me there where they spoke of reading large files. I'm not sure but I think he was using a generator.

Answer (score 11):

```
with open('myfile.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        # do something
        pass
```

Comment: Upvoting an answer that gives a code reading one line at a time, while the question was about the manner of reading a file by blocks, discredits the rep system and the upvoters.

Comment: @eyquem: the question was not about "reading a file by blocks"; the question was about "the best solution to process each line" of a large text file. In general, don't worry about reading block-by-block; sequential disk cache will take care of it for you.

Comment: You're right. You certainly  wrote your answer a tiny time after the question. I read all the answers 1 hour later and I was obnibulated by the code, and influenced by the fact that the accepted answer is the one giving a reading by blocks and by the comment of user653861: _"@philnext Exactly, I thought of working block"_ Excuse me, it wasn't against you (didn't wrote @...)

Comment: In fact I did not want to talk about block-simply because I wanted to leave open all options for reading a large file.
But I think, without being 100% sure that the block method would avoid memory errors, but I say without being certain.

Comment: @user653861: Your options are constrained by the structure of the data in the file. Lines of text: use `for line in f:`. 1024-byte blocks of binary data: loop over `f.read(1024)`. XML document: use an ElementTree implementation with `iterparse`, or a SAX parser. Et cetera. None of those methods will cause MemoryError. You can cause Memory Error by accumulating large data structures in your code. You say you want to process each line but you keep on mentioning "blocks" -- please make up your mind.

Answer (score 7):

Just using the standard file operations should work as long as you keep away from `readlines` and instead just use `readline`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is depending what you want to do with the datas...
I recommend to read by block and treat each block just after reading like :

```
fs = open(source, 'r')
while 1:
    txt = fs.readline(1000)
    < your treatement>
    if txt =="":
    break
fs.close()
```

Comment: @philnext Exactly, I thought of working block, is it better than the previously proposed solutions?

Comment: You're probably better off using `for line in the_file:...`, as that will automatically grab just each line for you (you won't need to find `\n`'s and assemble lines that span blocks, or anything complicated like that.

Comment: @user653861 The best way is to test all the proposed solutions because all are very light and esay to test. Do'nt forget to give us the results !!

Comment: @philnext I upvote because you answer to the question, you don't try to make the questioner think that he should do with a reading by line`. But you must replace ``readline(1000)`` with ``read(1000)`` in my opinion

Comment: @philnext: Your "solution" will truncate any line over 1000 bytes long; did you mean "readlines"? Whether readline or readlines, `txt == ""` will never be true, causing an exception at the end of file. You can't beat `for line in the_file` for simplicity AND speed.

Comment: @eyquem: read(1000) gives blocks of 1000 bytes which will usually contain the tail of a line plus some lines plus the head of another line -- why don't you write an answer showing the OP how to legibly pick that mess apart?

Comment: @eyquem, @John Machin : Yes I still understood the need to use read () instead of readline (). The response confirmed my philnext the block method for large files.

Comment: @user653861 Er, your last message is a little incomprehensible. I think english isn't your natural language. Personnellement, j'ai le même problème, et je comprendrais mieux des explications en français. Certains cherchent la petite bête, mais le débat se ramène à savoir ce que tu voulais faire: peux tu me confirmer que tu voulais bien lire un fichier par blocs, soit dans le cadre d'un algorithme particulier le demandant, soit pour mettre en pratique une lecture comme tu l'évoques. Et que donc _"What is the best solution to process each line of a text file "_ était une erreur dans ta question

Comment: @user653861: The "block method" is a nonsense for any size of file, if (as you say) you want to process LINES. If you don't want to process lines, edit your question. If you want to process LINES, use `for line in the_file:` -- then Python uses compiled C code to read large blocks and split them into lines; the answer of @philnext (with read instead of readline) reads blocks but doesn't pick the lines apart; that would need to be done laboriously and error-prone-ly in slower Python code.

Comment: It seems that French isn't the natural language of (Google|Bing) ... in `tu l'évoques`, one left the verb untranslated and the other thought it was something to do with "bishops"; both had no trouble with the more formal `vous l'évoquez`.

Comment: @eyquem : Je ne cherchais pas à lire un fichier par bloc, par contre je le proposais (voir mon code). Je cherchais exactement à traiter chaque ligne d'un fichier sans créer de "memory error" sur des fichiers de très grandes tailles et de façon la plus optimisée possible. C'est donc une question ouvertes à toutes propositions.En outre c'est purement théorique, je ne pourrais pas le tester, étant donner que je n'ai pas de fichier de cette taille, c'est surtout de la culture "python"

Comment: Bing Translate, edited where so indicated: """I was not looking for to read a file [by] block, however I proposed (see my code). I was looking for exactly to process each line of a file without creating a "memory error" on files of very large sizes, and the most optimized way possible. It is therefore a question open to all proposals. In addition it is purely theoretical, I could not test this, being given that I have no file of this size, it is mainly of culture "python" """

Comment: @John Machin : I want to treat a very large file line by line, and the solution I propose is to treat each line in several blocks of 1024 on my file. it's a good answer?

Comment: @user653861 OK. Donc j'ai vraiment compris la question comme il ne le fallait pas. Je pense que j'ai été induit en erreur par ton choix de la réponse de philnext comme éponse acceptée. Au départ je ne savais que penser de ce que tu voulais , comme cela est clair dans ma réponse; mais ensuite la réponse de philnext ayant été acceptée, j'en ai faussement déduit que c'était cette démarche que tu voulais. Par dessus le marché _"Exactly, I thought of working block,"_ a renforcé ma méprise. Je te souhaite d'avoir moins de problèmes avec tes prochaines questions. Pas facile de s'exprimer en anglais.

Comment: @eyquem : je te remercie de ton soutien ;) oui je ne suis pas une bête en anglais, mais j'adore ce site.

Comment: @user653861: Non, pas du tout, c'est une reponse tres mauvaise :) As I said in another comment, in general such a block would contain the tail of a line, several complete lines, and the head of a line. You would need to manage that yourself in slow and error-prone Python code, whereas the `for line in f:` approach does it correctly and rapidly.

Comment: @John Machin _" read(1000) gives blocks of 1000 bytes which will ..."_ Yes, I know. I said to replace ``readline(1000)`` with ``read(1000)`` when I was in the idea he wanted to read by block. I didn't know why he was wanting (I believed) to treat his file by block, I let him free to do so; but this condition given (I believed), it was ``read(1000)``  that was required. OK, now I have understood, he doesn't want that, then this remark of mine has no more interest. If he had to write a complicated code, I would have helped him. But I try to avoid to code without knowing exactly what.

Comment: @John Machin Interesting observation: Google mistakes "évoque" and "évêque" which in french means "bishop" !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the processes, the reading of a file goes through a buffer.

In this condition, `mon_fichier.read(1024)` don't fetch 1024 bytes directly from the file but from the buffer until this one will be exhausted, and then the buffer will be filled again by a new real reading of, say, 4096 or 8192 or 16384 or... bytes, I don't know precisely (think it's a power of 2, but even not sure)

Then, if you really want to treat blocks of bytes , I think that philnext's code is preferable. But `readline(1000)` must be replaced with `read(1000)` if you want to fetch exactly 1000 bytes; `readline(1000)` returns a line, and no more, even if the line is 4 characters long.

Treating a file by blocks may be what you really want to do , but it seems uncommon to me. It is more frequent to treat a file by lines, and in this case it's the Hugh Bothwell's code that is the right manner.

Comment: @user653861 I added something on read(1000) instead of readline(1000)

Comment: -1 The OP said "What is the best solution to process each line of a text file". The code of @philnext just doesn't work; see my comment on it. This answer is irrelevant noise; please consider deleting it.

Comment: @John Machin Where do you see in this answer that I would say the best solution would be to read by blocks ? At the time I wrote this answer, I was havin a fluctuant opinion. _"if you really want to treat blocks of bytes , I think that philnext's code is preferable"_ do you notice the **if** ? _"Treating a file by blocks may be what you really want to do , but it seems uncommon to me"_ Do you notice **may be** ? _"in this case (treating a file by lines) it's the Hugh Bothwell's code that is the right manner"_ Do you notice the **in this case** ?

Comment: @John Machin My subject in this answer was to warn the questioner that his idea of reading a file by block was may be a little partial; as far as I know, as I precised, to inform him that my remark might be incorrect . I was sure that if what I wrote was incorrect description, it was going to be corrected by experts.

Comment: @John Machin My answer isn't from a genius. But it has not to be deleted for the reason you put forward. On the contrary, I say exactly the same as Hugh Bothwell and you: _"It is more frequent to treat a file by lines, and in this case it's the Hugh Bothwell's code that is the right manner."_

Comment: @eyquem: Nowhere. Where do you see that I said that? The point of my first sentence was "lines, not blocks" ... "best solution" wasn't being stressed at all.

Comment: @John Machin My fault is after my answer. I think that it's because I saw the philnext's answer accepted that I concluded the option of reading by block was the desire of questioner. Fortunately, you was here to point the problems.

Comment: @John Machin When you write _"This answer is irrelevant noise"_ , I think it's because you judge my answer a bad answer to the written question wanting _"to process each line of a text file "_ , since the beginning of your comment is on this point. But, well, may be it is for the other reason ? : _"The code of @philnext just doesn't work;"_ Or maybe it is for these two reasons together... It becomes fastidious. I nearly prefer when I say a very big stupidity: in these cases, the debates are short.